# Split dataframe based on one column in r

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe of around 1M rows and want to split the dataframe based on one column & different ranges.
Example dataframe:

```
    length<-sample(rep(1:400),100)
    var1<-rnorm(1:100)
    var2<-sample(rep(letters[1:25],4))
    test<-data.frame(length,var1,var2)
```

I want to split the dataframe based on length at different ranges (ex: all rows for length between 1 and 50).

```
    range_length<-list(1:50,51:100,101:150,151:200,201:250,251:300,301:350,351:400)
```

I can do this by subsetting from the dataframe, ex: `test1<-test[test$length>1 &test$length<50,]`
But i am looking for more efficient way using "split" (just a line)

Comment: Take a look at the `cut` function. (and the `data.table` package while you're at it)

Answer (score 2):

```
range = seq(0,400,50)
split(test, cut(test$length, range))
```

But do heed Justin's suggestion and look into using `data.table` instead of `data.frame` and I'll also add that it's very unlikely that you actually *need* to split the data.frame/table.