# How to Separate a Dataset in R

Tags: r, model, dataset

I read a csv file into R.
There are options like quantity, price, size, and some others.
The same product has different size and therefore different prices.

How can I separate the dataset based on size and product so I can use it to build models?

Comment: Like `split(data, list(data$size, data$product))`?

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate. Do search on  `[r] split dataframe`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split dataframe based on one column in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727812/split-dataframe-based-on-one-column-in-r)

Comment: hey sorry, I wanna make some clarifications.  I want to split the data set in rows based on some conditions.  Such as there are sizes of big medium small for one product.  How do I seprate them into three datasets?  Also, how do I give two conditions for two variables?

Comment: Can you share some of your data?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install the package `dplyr`, it has a function called `filter`
which you can use to extract only the rows which meet your desired condition in a data set like this

```
DF <- filter(DataFrame1,Size=="Large")
```

and lets say you want to see `product = Rum`, `size = Large` and `price range = 10 - 40`, your command should look like:

```
Rums <- filter(DataFrame,product=="Rum" & size=="Large" & price>=10 & price<=40)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: how do i separate rows within a variable by giving conditions?

Comment: you could use the funtion `filter` also from `dplyr` like this

 `DF <- filter(MyDataFrame, Size=="Large" & Price>50)`

Comment: I missunderstood your question I'm going to edit the answer

Comment: hey Alfredo, I have another question.  how can i seprate the big database, lets say, every 7 records into a smaller dataset for maybe first 500 records, and after 500 records, every 10 records?  thanks again

Comment: Sorry for records you mean rows?

Comment: Hey! if the answer helped you it would help me if you could mark it answered.

Comment: Do you now want one smaller dataset or several?

Comment: several smaller dataset

Comment: for(i in 1:70) {ddat_<i> <- DataFrame1[(7*{i-1}):(7*i)] } #for the first 490

Comment: then for(i in 1:51) {ddat_<i> <- DataFrame1[(10*{i-1}):(10*i)] }